# Why is the remainder P when P000000 is divided by 13?

Tags: arithmetic

I was trying to solve this question, If the number $413283P759387$ is divisible by $13$,then what is the value of $P$? and stumbled upon this solution.

$413283P759387 = 0$ mod $13$

$4132830000000 + P000000 + 759387 = 0$ mod $13$

$4132830000000 = 0$ mod $13$

$P000000 = P x 10^6 = P$ mod $13$

$759387 = 5$ mod $13$

$(0 + P + 5) = 0$ mod $13$

P = 8

$\frac{4132836759387}{13} = 317910673799$

Can anyone please explain why is the remainder always $P$?

Comment: Try to find the remainder $10^6 \bmod 13$, and then $10^6P\equiv P \pmod {13}$.